# How to make Excel built-in InsertSymbol immediately close after inserting a character on Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible with VBA automatically close the window of Excel built-in InsertSymbol function immediately after inserting a character on cell

I'm trying to prevent the user entering more than one character into a cell by forcing the window to close with this built-in function